# PayPal Direct Payments Recurring disabled for this merchant

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create recurring profiles with Direct Payment, but I get this error (command `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`):

```
Array
(
   [TIMESTAMP] => [not-relevant]
   [CORRELATIONID] = [not-relevant]
   [ACK] => Failure
   [VERSION] => 50.0
   [BUILD] => 2764190
   [L_ERRORCODE0] => 11586
   [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled.
   [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => DPRP is disabled for this merchant.
   [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Non-recurring transactions and Express Checkout Recurring Payments are processed normally. Everything is working in SandBox. I've tried to contact PayPal's support, but they didn't know what the problem is. The error is self-descriptive, but I just can't find out how to enable the recurring payments. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure that when you create your sandbox account, you set the country to "United States" and the type to "Website Payments Pro". Setting it to "United Kingdom" will cause this error in your sandbox.

DPRP is enabled by default for United States sandbox accounts, so you shouldn't have to do anything else.

Since your sandbox account will now be in US Dollars, you'll have to add other currencies to it (this will save you problems later with test payments not accepting automatically). This can be done by going to:

1. "Enter Sandbox Test Site" on the "Test Accounts" page on developer.paypal.com
2. Sign in, and click the "Profile" link in the navigation bar
3. Click "Manage currency profiles", and add the currencies that you need to the account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have any problems with the sandbox environment. I get this error when I try to create recurring profile in the LIVE env. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1361077 Did you enable recurring payments in your account? Do you have Website Payments Pro enabled? (DPRP only works with WPP).

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473924/paypal-direct-recurring-payments-using-credit-debit-card-not-working-on-live-dp) that should help you.  You just need to get DPRP enabled, but because of changes with Payments Pro over the years there is lots of confusion about that right now, even within PayPal.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Angell, I have same issue in my paypal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile. Can you please guide me how I fix this error.